# No output from DOMPDF

Tags: command-line, dompdf

I am trying to run DOMPDF from a windows command line.  I am using the documentation from the domPDF website as a reference.  [DOMPDF usage](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage)

```
C:\>php -f C:\dompdf\dompdf.php -- C:\example.html
```

When I run this command I get nothing. No pdf, no errors, noting.  I have tried using the -v and the -d flags to turn the verbosity up.  I still get no output, neither to the screen or the command line.

When I run,

```
C:\>php -f C:\dompdf\dompdf.php -- -l
```

I actually get  a listing of the paper sizes, so PHP is installed and I am correctly calling the dompdf php file.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this would not actually produce output?

The html file is on the C: and has information in it.

Does anyone have any example of running DOMPDF from the command line, or see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would get absolutely nothing. It's been a while since I messed with the debugging options. It's possible that functionality has been lost during development but the documentation not updated. The file should be created in the same directory as the original. Does C:\example.pdf exist after running your command? You might try modifying the file argument to something like /example.html (perhaps PHP/dompdf doesn't like the C:\). (ref https://groups.google.com/d/topic/dompdf/aCQg6ahIrTo/discussion)

Comment: @BrianS Thank you for the response.  I unfortunately decided that DOMPDF was too slow for the table intensive application I needed it for, so I have completely abandoned this route to generate a PDF.

Comment: @kris-mitchell no worries. Extensive table usage can cause dompdf to consume a lot of resources. We hope to be able to address some of these issues once we have 0.6.0 final released. If you ever come back to dompdf we're always glad to try and help resolve problems.